# Redirect from non-www to www using 301 on IIS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, iis, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have hosted my website on a windows server on `1&1`. 
There, is not possible add on the web.config the the elements `<rewrite><rules>`... So I am using an `.htaccess` file... 
I am not so expert, I expected it would work just on Apache server. I was wrong! My `.hataccess` works also on IIS.

Here the code:

```
//Rewrite to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

//Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

The problem the redirect is done using a 302. I want a 301 redirect. I am using fiddler and this is the result:

[image]

The website where I have the problem is `www.renovahaus.it`
How can i solve my problem?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done with the URLRewrite module, in the case of 1&1 this is disabled in the web.config however when you use a .htaccess file the contents of the .htaccess are still translated to the underlying web.config.

You can read a great tutorial on the conversion process [here](http://www.phatz.com/301redirect.php)

But the summary is you are probably looking for the code block :-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which should transparently add the following to the web.config file (Even though you can't edit it directly)

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: but why .htaccess file redirect using 302 and not 301?